# Accessing the return value in the form of an array of R using RServe on Java

Tags: java, r, rserve

Previously, I was a beginner in the language R. I have a function R which returns an array of double.

Here's a snippet of R code to return that value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhZX1.png)

The output of this function is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63MJM.png)

Here's a snippet of Java code.

output = connection.eval("neuralNet10()").asDouble();

I want to access the value in Java using RServe.
Need help, I would really appreciate if anyone is willing to help thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't post pictures of your code, post actual code.

Everything coming back from Rserve is an array you can access it using `.asDoubles()` method - note the 's'